# Exclude entity field from update in ZF2 Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm in a situation that need to update a Doctrine2 Entity and exclude some fields.

With ZF2 i have an action to handle update using Zend\Form and validation filter. In particular `Dish` Entity have a blob column called `photo` that is **required**. During an update i want to replace the photo only if a new file is provided.

Here there are the source code for the entity and the controller action that update dish.

> Dishes\Entity\Dish.php

```
<?php
namespace Dishes\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity **/
class Dish
{
  /**
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  **/
  protected $id;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string")
  */
  protected $name;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="text")
  */
  protected $description;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  */
  protected $time;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  */
  protected $complexity;

  /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="blob")
  */
  protected $photo;

  /**
  * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
  *
  * @param string $property
  * @return mixed
  */
  public function __get($property)
  {
    return $this->$property;
  }

  /**
  * Magic setter to save protected properties.
  *
  * @param string $property
  * @param mixed $value
  */
  public function __set($property, $value)
  {
    $this->$property = $value;
  }
}
```

> Dishes\Controller\AdminController.php

```
public function editDishAction()
{
  //Params from url
  $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

  $objectManager = $this->objectManager;

  $hydrator = new DoctrineObject($objectManager, false);
  $form = new DishForm();

  $existingDish = $objectManager->find('Dishes\Entity\Dish', $id);

  if ($existingDish === NULL)
    $this->notFoundAction();

  $request = $this->getRequest();

  if ($request->isPost())
  {
    $filter = new DishFilter();
    $filter->get('photo')->setRequired(false);

    $form->setHydrator($hydrator)
      ->setObject($existingDish)
      ->setInputFilter($filter);

    $post = array_merge_recursive(
      $request->getPost()->toArray(),
      $request->getFiles()->toArray()
    );

    //Backup photo stream
    $imageData = $existingDish->photo;

    $form->setData($post);
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      //If user upload a new image read it.
      if(!empty($existingDish->photo['tmp_name']))
        $imageData = file_get_contents($existingDish->photo['tmp_name']);

      $existingDish->photo = $imageData;

      $objectManager->flush();

      $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/dishes');
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $data = $hydrator->extract($existingDish);
    unset($data['photo']);
    $form->setData($data);
  }

  return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
}
```

Actually i set `$dish->photo` property to `NULL` but this violate **DB NOT NULL** constraint.

How can I tell Doctrine to exclude a particular entity field from update at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine maps every column's `nullable` property in database level to `false` by default since you don't set any `nullable` flag in your annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="blob")
 */
 protected $photo;
```

This means, "Photo is required, you can't insert or update row's photo column with a null value".

If you want to have `null` values in your database, use the following annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="blob", nullable=true)
 */
 protected $photo;
```

and in it's setter don't forget the `null` default argument value:

```
 public function setPhoto($photo = null)
 {
    $this->photo = $photo;
 }
```

For the question; seems like you're setting a new Dish object on every edit operation in the action:

```
$form->setHydrator($hydrator)
     ->setObject(new Dish)
     ->setInputFilter($filter);
```

This is correct when creating new Dish objects. When editing, you have to set an already persisted Dish instance to the form:

```
// I'm just writing to explain the flow.
// Accessing the object repository in action level is not a good practice.
// Use a DishService for example.

$id           = 32; // Grab it from route or elsewhere
$repo         = $entityManager->getRepository('Dishes\Entity\Dish');
$existingDish = $repo->findOne((int) $id); 

$form->setHydrator($hydrator)
     ->setObject($existingDish)
     ->setInputFilter($filter);
```

I'm assuming this is edit action for an existing Dish.

So, the hydrator will correctly handle both changed and untouched fields on next call since you give an already populated Dish instance via the form.

I also recommend fetching the `DishFilter` from the `InputFilterManager` instead of creating it manually in action level:

```
// $filter = new DishFilter();
$filter = $serviceLocator->get('InputFilterManager')->get(DishFilter::class);
// Exclude the photo on validation:
$filter->setValidationGroup('name', 'description', 'time', 'complexity');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for help.
I edit my code to a working solution, in particular I don't disable validation on photo because if present I need to validate it.
Zend\Form set photo property to an empty array if no file is provided, so I backed up the stream provided by doctrine and restore it if there isn't new image.